# add action to drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, flask, web-applications

I'm working on the web app in where I have a dropbox, where a user can select any country from a dropdown box. I'm trying to add a feature, where a user can view a country's flag after it selects a particular country from the dropdown box. I added all the flags to my static folder already. I haven't been able to find too much information about it and I'm still pretty new to programming so anything would help.

Here's what I have:

```
index.html   
<form method="POST" action="/dropdown">
         <select name="country">
      <option value="{{countries[0]}}" selected>{{countries[0]}}</option>
      {% for country in countries[1:] %}
        <option value="{{country}}">{{country}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
        </select>
      <input type="submit" value ="Submit">
      </form>

main.py
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def dropdown():
    with open("countries.txt", 'r') as f:
        countries = [line.strip() for line in f]
    return render_template('index.html', countries=countries)
```

Comment: Either set up a dict that maps countries to their files, or use the country names/codes as file names (then just generate the link from that name).

Comment: Do you know any examples of this?

Comment: It's unclear to me which part you are unsure about. Do you need to know how to add images in general? How to add images based on the country? Or how to get the image as a result of a selection occuring?

Comment: How to add an image as a result of a selection? I need to somehow map the images to a country within a text file and I'm not sure how to do it and I wasn't able to find any good beginner level resources